# Check presence of multiple files as a whole in folder using Regex

Tags: python, file

I am checking a folder for the presence of several files:

- `Insertations.df`
- `Size.df`
- `State.df`

As all of these have quite specific routines I just check them one by one.
However for the next step it can be there is one or more additional version present:

```
$ ls *df
Insertations.df  Insertations_0.df  Size.df  Size_0.df  State.df  State_0.df
```

Including further iterations with 1...n.

I would like to figure out if a current iteration is present as a whole (Iterations, Size and State).

I'm not particularly good at Regexes, so I made a basic version running and it does something:

```
ipdb> [re.search('|'.join([fname+"_\d+.df" for fname in self.basiclist]),l) for l in os.listdir(".")]
[None, None, None, <re.Match object; span=(0, 17), match='Insertations_0.df'>, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, <re.Match object; span=(0, 10), match='State_0.df'>, None, <re.Match object; span=(0, 9), match='Size_0.df'>, None, None]
```

This list contains just the filenames:

```
ipdb> self.basiclist
['Insertations', 'Size', 'State']
```

I'm not sure what to do with my result-list. Is there a proper way to counter check against a list with Regexes? Also until which iteration all the files are present?

Answer (score 0):

It's really not clear what you are trying to ask, or why you want a regex solution. Something like this? This returns the files whose names match your regex.

```
for file in os.scandir():
    for fname in self.basiclist:
        if re.match(rf"^{fname}_\d+\.df$", file):
            matches.append(file)
    else:
        continue
    break
```

This can be reduced to a `filter` expression if you really want to force it to a one-liner, but it's kind of obscure.

```
list(filter(lambda file:
    any(re.match(rf"^{fname}_\d+\.df$", file) for fname in self.basiclist),
  os.scandir()))
```

Or are you trying to ask for which number suffixes all three files are present? That would perhaps look something like

```
from pathlib import Path

found = []
for insfile in Path().glob('Insertations_*.df'):
    try:
        suffix = int(insfile.stem.split('_', 1)[1])
    except ValueError:
        # not a number, so not interesting
        continue
    candidates = [Path(x + "_" + str(suffix) + ".df") for x in ['Size', 'State']]
    if all(candidate.exists() for candidate in candidates):
        found.append([insfile] + candidates)
```

This loops over the `Insertations_*.df` files and checks if both the other files exist with the same suffix.